# Download file from SQL Server database using Ajax and web service in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I've  tried to download a specific file from a SQL Server database using Ajax and a web service and a code is working without errors and still can't download the file.Here is the code

My HTML

```html
<input id="btn_download" type="button" value="download_att" />
```

my ajax function to read id for file retrive

```js
$('#btn_download').click(function () {
                id = $('#Tid').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'WebService1.asmx/DownloadFile',
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    data: '{id:' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("s");
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

my webservice

```
[ScriptMethod]
[WebMethod]
public void DownloadFile(table id )
{
    byte[] bytes;

    string fileName, contentType;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TesterConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select id,image from attach where id=@Id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id.id);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            sdr.Read();
            bytes = (byte[])sdr["image"];
            contentType = sdr["id"].ToString();
            fileName = sdr["id"].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();
    }


    httpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    httpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    httpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    httpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    httpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    httpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    httpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    httpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: No. You cannot download files by using ajax request.

Comment: why cannot download files by using ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
  [ScriptMethod]
        [WebMethod]
        public void DownloadFile(int id)
        {

            byte[] bytes;
var id =HTTPContext.Current.Request.Form["id"];//add this line to ref to id
            string fileName, contentType;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TesterConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select image from test where Id=@Id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["image"];
                    // var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\a.png");
                    contentType = sdr["id"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["filename"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;// "image/png";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();


        }
```

**javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            function downloadUrl(url) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', url, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        var filename = "";
                        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                        }
                        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

                        var blob = typeof File === 'function'
                            ? new File([this.response], filename, { type: type })
                            : new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
                        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                        } else {
                            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                            if (filename) {
                                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                                var a = document.createElement("a");
                                // safari doesn't support this yet
                                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                                } else {
                                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                                    a.download = filename;
                                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                                    a.click();
                                }
                            } else {
                                window.location = downloadUrl;
                            }

                            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                var params = {};
                params.id = $('#YOUR ID');//add this line to send id 
                xhr.send($.param(params));
            }

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                downloadUrl("/WebService1.asmx/DownloadFile")
            });
        })
```

Comment: i got error "an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: @HelloItsMe error in retrieving byte array from database

Comment: Code is complete debug your code and let me know the exact line number

Comment: comment this line `//bytes = (byte[])sdr["image"];`   and uncomment `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\a.png");` copy an image in `c:\temp` named `a.png'

Comment: @HelloItsMe just try

Comment: i try this and same error in line "ontentType = sdr["id"].ToString();"

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = "select image from test where Id=@Id";`  check this line

Comment: 'cmd.CommandText = "select id,image from attach where id=@Id"; '
my table attach in database contain 2 filed only id and image

Comment: what is the value of id

Comment: the value of id is int

Comment: I mean how you are passing the value to ajax

Comment: in your code how to pass id from javascript to the webservice DownloadFile function

Comment: currently it's hard coded in javascript change the function signature and accept

Comment: how to pass id from javascript to the webservice DownloadFile function in your code

Comment: can you help hear
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375932/issue-in-deploying-project-using-asp-net-2012-with-oracle-database-11g?noredirect=1#comment84035133_48375932